# onDestroy gets called whenever screen turns off

Tags: android, screen, ondestroy

I am aware of the fact that this problem has been reported earlier and I have used all the recommended solutions but none has helped so far.

As mentioned in the title, `onDestroy()` is called every time screen turns off. It doesn't happen if a service is ON.

Application has fixed orientation and hence

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

As per some earlier suggestions, I added

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

etc. I also implemented `onConfigurationChanged()` but it never gets called.

Two important points:

1. We are facing the problem only on one device in our test setup,
   Samsung Duo running 4.0.4. On all other devices, this is not an
   issue.
2. This issue is not happening with other apps running on the same
   device.

Will appreciate your help.

Thanks

**Update**: It seems that setting these flag is causing the issue. Removing them solves but they were used for a reason so any other insight will be appreciated.

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
```

Comment: What Android version do you target? I would try to add also `screenSize` into manifest configChanges, but I am not sure about solving your problem with it.

Comment: Thanks, already tried. Not helping. Target api level >= 8

Comment: What your app does ? Using any `WakeLocks` or something ?

Comment: No, it's just a simple login activity.

Comment: Having the same issue too. I call an activity from an Intent in a Service. Have you solved this issue yet?

Comment: @XO I posted an update (pls see bottom of the post), see if it helps

Comment: @yumoji: Thanks for the response! I did try it- and found out the other night that my issue was related to 'android:noHistory="true"' in the Manifest file. Once removed, the activity was no longer being destroyed. I wonder if there's any relations between our solutions?

Comment: @yumoji Sorry, ay late in seeing the update. REsumed development, I'll confirm when I get a change.